# Windows 7 Notification Icons Problems

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, notifications

I'm experiencing a problem in Windows 7 x64 where there are a large number of blank spaces in my "notifications icons" popup.
These same gaps appear if I change the setting to show all icons.  If I hover of the gaps, the spaces indicate that I've hovered over them, but there is no text popup indicating what I'm hovering over, and there's no reaction by right or left clicking on the space.

There's nothing unusual running in my process list, and my system has come up clean using a variety of malware, spyware and antivirus checks.

I'd like to get it back to normal.  I've tried closing the running applications, but it doesn't seem to resolve the issue.  Any ideas?

There's an image of the problem here: http://twitpic.com/26tttz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try [deleting the icon cache](http://www.winvistaclub.com/t71.html)?

Comment: Deleting  the icon cache did the trick.  For Windows 7, I followed these instructions:

http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/how-to-rebuild-the-icon-cache-in-windows-vista/

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This also helped me fix error 0x80243004 when running Windows Update.

Answer (score 2):

From: http://www.fixitjim.net/2012/11/fix-corrupt-or-blank-windows-7-system.html

> 1. Open Regedit via Start-->Search
> 2. Open Task Manager via CTRL-ALT-DEL
> 3. Find Explorer.exe in the list and end the Process
> 4. Go back to Regedit
> 5. Select HKEY_CURRENTUSER
> 6. Click Edit-->Find
> 7. Search for IconStreams  Or navigate directly to HKEY_CURRENTUSER\SOFTWARE\CLASSES\Local
>      Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TrayNotify\
> 8. Delete IconStreams
> 9. Search or navigate to PastIconStreams
> 10. Delete this key as well
> 11. Hit CTRL-ALT-DEL
> 12. Start Task Manager
> 13. Click File-->Run
> 14. Type, Explorer.exe
> 15. The issue should be resolved.

This link also has same solution: 
https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/36510-how-to-fix-blank-system-tray-icons

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](https://superuser.com/help/referencing" class="soup-https-fixed). You should block quote text that has been written by some else. See [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help). I've fixed it for you this time, but please pay attention to this in future.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the Customize option to see what programs belong to the missing icons?

Maybe you can restore the default settings.

Comment: When I open the customize dialogue box it shows a number of items with no icons to their left, so I'm assuming those entries are the ones that aren't being shown.  I just have no idea why they don't have their corresponding icons.

Comment: Did you try hitting the "Turn system icons on or off" link at the bottom of the customize screen?  What description was next to the items with no icon?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  The icon cache suggestion below turned out to resolve my problem.